# What does the standard library guarantee about self move assignment?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, move-semantics

What does the C++11 standard say about self move assignment in relation to the standard library? To be more concrete, what, if anything, is guaranteed about what `selfAssign` does?

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T> selfAssign(std::vector<T> v) {
  v = std::move(v);
  return v;
}
```

Comment: @Mark I don't think this is a duplicate. That question is about writing your own. This question is about what the standard library guarantees.

Comment: Note that this does *not* involve the self-move-assignment of `T`.

Comment: @Xeo I removed that line. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: voting to reopen as the marked "duplicate" does not cover guarantees on standard containers' move-assignment behaviour, and none of the answers provide Standard references like Howard Hinnant's answer to this thread

Answer (score 46, accepted):

17.6.4.9 Function arguments [res.on.arguments]

> 1 Each of the following applies to all arguments to functions defined
>   in the C++ standard library, unless explicitly stated otherwise.
>
> ...
>
> - If a function argument binds to an rvalue reference parameter, the implementation may assume that this parameter is a unique reference to
>     this argument. [ Note: If the parameter is a generic parameter of the
>     form T&& and an lvalue of type A is bound, the argument binds to an
>     lvalue reference (14.8.2.1) and thus is not covered by the previous
>     sentence. — end note ] [ Note: If a program casts an lvalue to an
>     xvalue while passing that lvalue to a library function (e.g. by
>     calling the function with the argument move(x)), the program is
>     effectively asking that function to treat that lvalue as a temporary.
>     The implementation is free to optimize away aliasing checks which
>     might be needed if the argument was anlvalue. —endnote]

So, the implementation of `std::vector<T, A>::operator=(vector&& other)` is allowed to assume that `other` is a prvalue.  And if `other` is a prvalue, self-move-assignment is not possible.

What is likely to happen:

`v` will be left in a resource-less state (0 capacity).  If `v` already has 0 capacity, then this will be a no-op.

**Update**

The [latest working draft, N4618](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4618.pdf) has been modified to clearly state that in the `MoveAssignable` requirements the expression:

```
t = rv
```

(where `rv` is an rvalue), `t` need only be the equivalent value of `rv` prior to the assignment if `t` and `rv` do not reference the same object.  And regardless, `rv`'s state is unspecified after the assignment.  There is an additional note for further clarification:

> `rv` must still meet the requirements of the library component that is using it, whether or not `t` and `rv` refer to the same object.

Comment: If I understand your quote correctly, the function `selfAssign` then invokes undefined behavior because the preconditions of the move assignment operator are not met. My understanding is that `std::swap` will do self move assignment on the call `std::swap(v, v)`. Does that make it undefined behavior to call `std::swap(v, v)`?

Comment: Interesting. This would mean that `&&` implies `__restrict` for arguments then; I wonder if any compiler takes advantage of this yet.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: That's only what the standard says about *it's own* functions; that's not a general statement about `&&` parameters. You would not be restricted to that in code you write.

Comment: @BjarkeH.Roune: swap(v, v) is legal and required to work.  And it typically does because the self-move-assignment is done with a moved-from value (assuming we're not talking about vector which has a specialized swap which is also required to work with self-swap).  In the generic self-swap, you're move assigning from an unspecified value to an unspecified value.  So it really doesn't matter what happens as long as it doesn't crash.  swap(t, t) requires `T` to be `MoveAssignable`.  That requirement holds even if `T` is in a moved-from state.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I'm not sure I understand your reasoning. I made the topic [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129031/on-implementing-stdswap-in-terms-of-move-assignment-and-move-constructor).

Comment: Note that a self-move-assigned container that doesn’t preserve its state would break the proposed requirement for move-assigned containers (depending on allocator) to not invalidate iterators: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2321

Answer (score 5):

There is [a relevant post by Eric Niebler](https://ericniebler.com/2017/03/31/post-conditions-on-self-move/) with multiple links, e.g. to [this answer by Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9322542/767632).

The latest С++20 working draft (N4861) is still kind of ambiguous on the matter for my taste. However, there is a recent [Library Working Group issue 2839](https://wg21.link/lwg2839) which adds the following explicit statement at `[lib.types.movedfrom]/2`:

> An object of a type defined in the C++ standard library may be move-assigned (11.4.6 [class.copy.assign]) to itself. Such an assignment places the object in a valid but unspecified state unless otherwise specified.

It was already in the N4885 working draft of C++23.

So, `selfAssign` is guaranteed to not cause undefined behavior and, as there are no extra guarantees for `std::vector`, leave `v` in some valid state.