# Behaviour of move-assignment to self

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
    std::vector<int> w(20, 123), x;
    w = std::move(w);
    std::cout << w.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Output on g++ 4.8.3: `0`

Of course, the standard says that the move-assignment operator leaves the operand in an unspecified state. For example if the code were `x = std::move(w);` then we would expect `w.size()` to be zero.

However, is there a specified ordering or other clause that covers the self-move case?  Is it unspecified whether size is `0` or `20`, or something else, or undefined behaviour? Do the standard containers have any defined semantics here?

Related: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322174/move-assignment-operator-and-if-this-rhs) talks about whether you should care about self-move in your own classes, but does not discuss whether standard containers' move-assignment operators do, and doesn't provide Standard references.

NB. Is this exactly identical to `w = static_cast< std::vector<int> && >(w);` or does the fact that `std::move` is a function make a difference?

Comment: Interesting. Table 96 (in §23.2.1) says that `a = rv;` where `a` is a value of a container type and `rv` is a non-const rvalue of a container type, has the operational semantics that "All existing elements
of `a` are either move assigned to or destroyed" and the postcondition that "`a` shall be equal to the value that `rv` had before this assignment". Hard to meet both in case of self-move-assignment.

Comment: Question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13127916/2352671

Comment: @40two That question is itself marked "duplicate" of the question I linked which is definitely NOT a duplicate!   (I guess your linked question didn't come up in my search because the search skips duplicates).  Can we request that your linked question be un-marked as "duplicate" as it actually has useful discussion.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Look please at the answer. IMHO it answers your question.

Comment: @40two The answer you link does answer my question; however I'm saying that the question of which that answer is an answer, is marked duplicate when it should not be. (Or was - it has been reopened now)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Someone reopened it. IMHO falsely closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

§17.6.4.9 [res.on.arguments]:

> Each of the following applies to all arguments to functions defined in the C++ standard library, unless explicitly stated otherwise.
>
> - [...]
> - If a function argument binds to an rvalue reference parameter, the implementation may assume that
>   this parameter is a unique reference to this argument. [ Note: If the parameter is a generic parameter of the form `T&&` and an lvalue of type `A` is bound, the argument binds to an lvalue reference (14.8.2.1) and thus is not covered by the previous sentence. — end note ] [ Note: If a program casts an lvalue to an xvalue while passing that lvalue to a library function (e.g. by calling the function with the argument `move(x)`), the program is effectively asking that function to treat that lvalue as a temporary. The implementation is free to optimize away aliasing checks which might be needed if the argument was an lvalue. — end note ]

Since "the implementation may assume that this parameter is a unique reference to this argument", and self-move-assignment would violate this assumption, it has undefined behavior.

See also [LWG issue 1204](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1204).

Comment: That clause doesn't cover the case `v = static_cast< V&& >(v);` that I mention at the end of the question

Comment: @MattMcNabb It does - you are still passing an rvalue reference to the move assignment operator, which is a standard library function. Whether you obtained it by `move` or `static_cast` is irrelevant.

Comment: The case `w = std::move(w);` seems to be covered by the first "Note:", unless I am misunderstand that Note?  Talking about binding `w` to the parameter of `std::move`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The answer to your last question is "yes". Your static_cast has the same effect as `std::move` in this situation.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The problem is binding the result of `std::move(w)` to the argument of `vector::operator=(vector &&)`, not binding `w` to the argument of `std::move`.

Comment: OK, so the resolution is that `t = std::move(t);` is undefined behaviour regardless of what the type of `t` is?

Comment: @MattMcNabb If `t` is a standard library type, it would appear so.

Comment: So it's not UB if a user-defined type implements its own move-assignment operator. And if a UDT has a defaulted move-assignment operator then it depends on whether any of the member variables or base classes (which may be templated!) have any standard library types amongst them...

Comment: I assume that if an implementation can optimize away aliasing checks, then another consequence of the UB is that resources may be leaked? e.g., std::vector move-assignment ends up setting it's underlying vector memory to nullptr, without releasing the memory? This is weak.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Ugh. Howard Hinnant [claims](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13129446/2756719) that `MoveAssignable` requires the type to tolerate self-move assignment, resulting in an unspecified value. That means a) the specification of `MoveAssignable` in the standard is off, as it has a postcondition that "`t` is equivalent to the value of `rv` before the assignment", which doesn't make sense if self-move-assignment leaves the object in an unspecified state; and b) either 1) no standard type is  `MoveAssignable` or 2) somehow violating this assumption merely lead to unspecified behavior and not UB.

Comment: @BrettHale I can't think of an implementation of move assignment (without checking for self-moves) that would leak in cases of self-moves.

Comment: @TC I *think* that he is only referring to `std::swap` there. And perhaps the definition of `MoveAssignable` only applies to the case where `rv` is a variable, not a reference .  (`t = t;` would be copy-assignment, not move)

Comment: @BrettHale naively one could write `{ this->p = other->p; other->p = nullptr; }` - works for all cases except self-moves

Comment: @MattMcNabb You still have to destroy whatever that's previously pointed to by `this->p`, thus you won't leak anything.

Comment: @MattMcNabb rvalues include xvalues like `std::move(t)`, and I read HH's comments as making a general statement about `MoveAssignable`.