# Is std::swap(x, x) guaranteed to leave x unchanged?

Tags: c++, c++11, swap

This question is based on discussion below a [recent blog post by Scott Meyers](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/06/the-drawbacks-of-implementing-move.html).

It seems "obvious" that `std::swap(x, x)` should leave `x` unchanged in both C++98 and C++11, but I can't find any guarantee to that effect in either standard. C++98 defines `std::swap` in terms of copy construction and copy assignment, while C++11 defines it in terms of move construction and move assignment, and this seems relevant, because in C++11 (and C++14),  17.6.4.9 says that move-assignment need not be self-assignment-safe:

> If a function argument binds to an rvalue reference parameter, the implementation may assume that this parameter is a unique reference to this argument. ... [ Note: If a program casts an lvalue to an
>   xvalue while passing that lvalue to a library function (e.g. by calling the function with the argument
>   move(x)), the program is effectively asking that function to treat that lvalue as a temporary. The
>   implementation is free to optimize away aliasing checks which might be needed if the argument was
>   an lvalue. —end note ]

The [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1204) that gave rise to this wording makes the consequence clear:

> this clarifies that move assignment operators need not perform the traditional if (this != &rhs) test commonly found (and needed) in copy assignment operators.

But in C++11 and C++14, `std::swap` is expected to use this implementation,

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T& lhs, T& rhs)
{
  auto temp(std::move(lhs));
  lhs = std::move(rhs);
  rhs = std::move(temp); 
}
```

and the first assignment is performing an assignment to self where the argument is an rvalue. If the move assignment operator for `T` follows the policy of the standard library and doesn't worry about assignment to self, this would seem to court undefined behavior, and that would mean that `std::swap(x, x)` would have UB, as well.

That's worrisome even in isolation, but if we assume that `std::swap(x, x)` was supposed to be safe in C++98, it also means that C++11/14's `std::swap` could silently break C++98 code.

So is `std::swap(x, x)` guaranteed to leave `x` unchanged? In C++98? In C++11? If it is, how does this interact with 17.6.4.9's permission for move-assignment to not be self-assignment-safe?

Comment: 1. Why do you believe that swap must be implemented using move? I do not see that in the standard. 2. I don't see the assignment to self in your swap implementation!?

Comment: @WernerHenze: 1. Per 20.2.2 of the Standard, the requirement for swappable types is that they must be MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable. 2. In the call `std::swap(x, x)`, the parameters `lhs` and `rhs` are the same object, so `lhs = std::move(rhs)` is an assignment to self.

Comment: You are right about 2., I missed that. Regarding 1.: the standard does not give an implementation, so I do not think that this is a defect in the standard but in the implementation. The implementation could check if &lhs==&rhs and then skip the move.

Comment: DR1204 which you linked to is talking about move-assignment operators for standard library implementations. That doesn't apply as a general statement to user-defined classes.

Comment: BTW, it does not matter when self-move-assignment damages the value in your swap implementation. After the self-assignment, there is a move-assignment to not-self which resurrects the original value, provided that such not-self-assignments do not damage the value.

Comment: is this supposed to be [tag:language-lawyer]?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this may be covered, at least in C++20<sup>(a)</sup>, by the `[utility.requirements]` section which states:

> `15.5.3.2` describes the requirements on swappable types and swappable expressions.

That referenced section, `[swappable.requirements]`, further states (my emphasis in the final two bullet points):

> An object `t` is swappable with an object `u` if and only if:
>
> - the expressions `swap(t, u)` and `swap(u, t)` are valid when evaluated in the context described below; and
> - these expressions have the following effects:
>
>   - ***the object referred to by `t` has the value originally held by `u`; and***
>   - ***the object referred to by `u` has the value originally held by `t`.***

It seems to me that, if self-swap somehow damaged the contents, those bolded sections would be invalidated, meaning that they *wouldn't* be swappable.

That same section also later states:

> An rvalue or lvalue `t` is swappable if and only if `t` is swappable with ***any*** rvalue or lvalue, respectively, of type `T`.

There's no waffling around with self-swaps there, it *clearly* states *any* rvalue or lvalue (respectively), including itself.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Both these constraints also exist in C++17, c++14, and C++11, anything older than that, I don't really care about :-)

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Yes, `std::swap(x, x)` is always fine (for any x of MoveAssignable type T).

As I understand, self-move-assignment might leave the object in a valid but unspecified state, so it's not UB, and, as mentioned by @j6t in the comment, `std::swap` brings back the original value, so it should work.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127455/what-does-the-standard-library-guarantee-about-self-move-assignment) Q&A Howard Hinnant writes in the comment:

> swap(v, v) is legal and required to work. And it typically does because the self-move-assignment is done with a moved-from value (assuming we're not talking about vector which has a specialized swap which is also required to work with self-swap). In the generic self-swap, you're move assigning from an unspecified value to an unspecified value. So it really doesn't matter what happens as long as it doesn't crash. swap(t, t) requires T to be MoveAssignable. That requirement holds even if T is in a moved-from state.

---

As I understand, this is (finally! in the upcoming C++23) covered by [LWG 2839: Self-move-assignment of library types, again](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2839) (which came after [LWG 2468:  Self-move-assignment of library types](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2468)).

2839 contains the following:

> An object of a type defined in the C++ standard library may be move-assigned (11.4.6 [class.copy.assign]) to itself. Such an assignment places the object in a valid but unspecified state unless otherwise specified.

The part of the standard you quoted now [looks like](https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.arguments):

> If a function argument is bound to an rvalue reference parameter, the implementation may assume that this parameter is a unique reference to this argument, except that the argument passed to a move-assignment operator may be a reference to *this ([lib.types.movedfrom]).

I.e. it seems to have an exception specifically for self-move-assignment to not be UB.

See also [Eric Niebler's article](https://ericniebler.com/2017/03/31/post-conditions-on-self-move/) and the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322174/move-assignment-operator-and-if-this-rhs) it's based on. In the answer Howard Hinnant (lead author of libc++) writes that:

> Some will argue that swap(x, x) is a good idea, or just a necessary evil. And this, if the swap goes to the default swap, can cause a self-move-assignment.
>
> I disagree that swap(x, x) is ever a good idea. If found in my own code, I will consider it a performance bug and fix it.

The Core Guidelines however [have a point](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#Rc-move-self) about allowing self-move-assignment in user-defined types. But that's just an advice (which e.g. the standard library apparently doesn't adhere to). It mentions:

> Note The ISO standard guarantees only a “valid but unspecified” state for the standard-library containers. Apparently this has not been a problem in about 10 years of experimental and production use. Please contact the editors if you find a counter example. The rule here is more caution and insists on complete safety.