# Possible bug in boost visitation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I have the following error message:

```
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:207: typename Visitor::result_type boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl(int, int, Visitor &, VPCV, mpl::true_, NBF, W *, S *) [W = mpl_::int_<20>, S = boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_step<boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_end>, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_end> >, Visitor = boost::detail::variant::copy_into, VPCV = const void *, NBF = boost::variant<TypeInfo, int, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_]: Assertion `false' failed.
```

This happens when I am passing `std::vector<A>` as a parameter by value to some function and `A` is defined as `using A = boost::variant<B, int>;`.
To be simple, `B` is defined like this:

```
class B
{
    Data data;
    std::vector< boost::variant<std::shared_ptr<C>, B> > vec;
};
```

`B` is `TypeInfo` in error message.

```
void func(std::vector<B> vec); //signature

auto result = func(that_vector_with_variants); //that line causes an error
```

I have found similar bug here https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5146

My question is: Is it a bug in boost? How can I make my code work?

Update:

I think that I have to add that if I change `std::vector<boost::variant<std::shared_ptr<C>, B> > vec;` to `std::vector<boost::variant<C*, B> > vec;` then everything works.

Comment: What is the visitor? You don't show any related code. You're using a variant. In a container. Good. That's basically all we know for now

Comment: @sehe, It is the main problem, that it is some internal visitor. When I look backtrace in gdb, I see that error appeared during copying vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going out on a limb, and from reading that bug report, you maybe inadvertantly doing something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

using P = boost::shared_ptr<int>;
using V = boost::variant<P, int>;
using C = std::vector<V>;

int main() {
    P p = boost::make_shared<int>(42);
    assert(p.unique());

    C v = { p };
    assert(!p.unique());

    v = std::move(v);
    assert(!p.unique()); // WHOOPS assert fails
}
```

<sub>Of course this sample is contrived², because I don't know your actual code/use case.</sub>

The last assert fails. This is due to the fact that the order of the operations, internally, is such that the original variant is cleared (and the contained value destructed) *before* the new value is assigned:

> "Never-Empty" Guarantee
>
> While the never-empty guarantee might at first seem "obvious," it is in fact not even straightforward how to implement it in general
>
> Cf. [The "Ideal" Solution: False Hopes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant/design.html#variant.design.never-empty.memcpy-solution) from Boost Variant "Design Overview"

So, had we not had a "reference" to the `int` in `p`, this operation would have destroyed the instance before it was reassigned.

In this case, it looks more like a pattern of use (essentially in-place modification with smart pointers ¹) to avoid. In this particular case, these appear to work (on my compiler/library implementation):

```
std::move(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin());
// or
std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(v.end()), v.begin());
// or
v.assign(std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(v.end()));
```

But I'd **certainly** prefer to write it more like

```
C tmp = std::move(v); 
v = std::move(tmp);
```

Just because there are no guarantees otherwise.

---

¹ always a hazard! Even Scott Meyers feel for this in his "More Effective C++", see the **[erratum p.200/202](http://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/mec++-errata.html)**

² related: [What does the standard library guarantee about self move assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127455/what-does-the-standard-library-guarantee-about-self-move-assignment/13127916#13127916)

Comment: BTW, what is `std::move(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin());`? there is no such overload.

Comment: Oops. I never knew that. thanks for teaching me something new again.