# Exception safety guarantee and std::move()

Tags: c++, c++11, exception-safety

During some implementation I stuck with the problem about exception safety guarantee and using `std::move()`. I know that SO is not a good place to ask "what is your opinion" (class template `Boo`) kind of a question but here I would like to make sure if my understanding is correct and after you read this question maybe you can direct me to the right path.

Consider following code:

```
struct Foo {
    using Y = std::vector<std::string>;
    using X = std::vector<Y>;

    void add (Y y) {
        src.push_back (std::move (y));      // (1)
        src = process (std::move (src));    // (2)         
    }

private:
    X process (X&& vec) {                   // (F)
        for (auto& v : vec) {
            v.resize (10);                  // (3)
        }
        return std::move (vec);
    }


    X src;
};
```

Take a look at the `add()` member function, if an exception is
thrown from (1) and according to the n4296 [vector.modifiers/1]

> If an exception is thrown while inserting a single element at the end and `T` is `CopyInsertable` or `is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value` is `true`, there are no effects.

then strong guarantee is preserved, am I right?

If we look at the (2) then exception can also be thrown here, because (3) can throw an exception. Correct me if I am wrong:
In this situation (2) if I move `src` to the `process()` member function and exception is thrown from `process()` then `src` is
unspecified and that means that only basic guarantee is preserved?

To make `add()` member function strong guarantee should I change
(2) and (F) respectively to:

```
src = process (src); // (2)
X process (X vec);   // (F)
```

?

So if `Foo::src` has huge number of elements, then making strong
guarantee is associated with less efficiency (because extra copy has to be made) ?

Maybe guarantee level should be left to decide by the user of the class, by making it a class template, similar to this:

```
struct S {};
struct B {};

template <typename T>
struct Boo {
    using Y = std::vector<std::string>;
    using X = std::vector<Y>;

    void add (Y y) {
        src.push_back (std::move (y));
        src = process_helper (typename std::is_same<T, S>::type {});
    }


private:
    X process_helper (std::true_type) {
        return process (src);
    }

    X process_helper (std::false_type) {
        return process (std::move (src));
    }

    X process (X vec) {
        for (auto& v : vec) {
            v.resize (10);                  
        }
        return std::move (vec);
    }

    X src;
};
```

Is it a good or bad idea?

Comment: `process` indirectly does `src = std::move(src)` [which is a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127455).

Comment: @nwp: I don't think so: It first move constructs a temporary.

Comment: Why not `X process (X&& vec_in) { auto vec = std::move(vec_in);`, or just `X process (X vec)`?  Ah, because the call strips out your src.  Really to fix it you want `src.push_back (std::move (y));` to "process' `y` before inserting, or keep track of how to invert everything (using no exception checks to reduce overhead)?

Comment: @Yakk I didn't mention the whole idea which stands behind the `resize()` call, because I didn't think it is worth, but if you suggested solution to process `y` before inserting, I have to worry you (or me), I can not do this, because I want to have all `src` rows to have exactly the same length, which means if I pass `y` which have different (greater) size than any row in the `src` then I have to take action to resize rest of them to keep them equal (to y). Reverting after exception can still be an option.

Comment: Personally: As long as you are not writing a general purpose library, I'd have a closer look at the calling code and see, whether it requires the strong exception gurantee or not and decide for one variant accordingly. In particular, it is rare that an application actually proceeds execution, after a std::bad_alloc is thrown.

Comment: Note that this question is **not** about `std::move()`; it's about passing rvalues to functions. `std::move()` is one way of getting rvalues, but it's not the only way. It's just a fancy cast, and doesn't do any data modification.

Comment: If move (construction) can throw, and you need capacity increase, there is no way to generate strong exception guarantee without copies.

Comment: Can you explain what the point of all this is. E.g. are you trying to atomically add an item to a vector and resize all items.