# C++20 std::move in self assignment

Tags: c++, c++20, stdmove

Most answers, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127455/what-does-the-standard-library-guarantee-about-self-move-assignment) one, point out that `std::move` is not meant to be used in self-assignment. 
I do, however, see the **Possible Implementation** of `accumulate` in official [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) via self move assignment:

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
constexpr // since C++20
T accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        init = std::move(init) + *first; // std::move since C++20
    }
return init;
}
```

Is it safe only since C++20? What is happening internally? 
The [EXP63-CPP](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/EXP63-CPP.+Do+not+rely+on+the+value+of+a+moved-from+object) states that:

> it should be assumed that the only operations that may be safely performed on a moved-from object instance are reinitialization through assignment into the object or terminating the lifetime of the object by invoking its destructor

Looks like reinitialization is completely legal.

Comment: That's not an official reference. The closest to an official reference you can get without paying for it is the drafts of the standards.

Comment: The example is moving `init` to the `operator+` not to the `operator=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a self-assignment.

A self-assignment would be `init = std::move(init);`, and you have `init = std::move(init) + *first;`.

Comment: could you elaborate more on the differences in `init` object state between [self-assignment] and [not self-assignment containing self-move]. And I'll totally accept you answer

Comment: @user2376997 I'm not sure how to elaborate here. Overloaded `+` in general returns by value rather than a reference to its left operand. If it returns a reference to the left operand for your type, then yes, it would be a self-assignment.