# Is it optimized when erasing the n last items in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

As I know, if the order of the vector is not important, it is faster to use the `swap`-`pop_back` idiom for removing an **single item** from `std::vector`. For example:

```
auto it = std::find(my_vec.begin(),my_vec.end(),SOME_VALUE);
std::swap(*it,my_vector.back());
my_vector.pop_back();
```

The previous example *avoids* copying many elements.

From the same perspective, if I want to call `std::vector::erase` on a range which is represent the last `n` items of a `std::vector`, would it be optimised and behaves like multi `pop_back`?

**Example:**

```
auto it = std::find(my_vec.begin(),my_vec.end(),SOME_VALUE);
my_vec.erase(it,my_vec.end()); // Erase everything from 'it' and beyond
```

Comment: Why do you think it would be "optimal" for it to behave as "multi `pop_back`"? That sounds quite sub-optimal to me.

Comment: You mean: why do I think that multi pop_back is a good thing at all ?

Comment: I mean why is it particularly good for removing the last n elements.

Comment: As far as I know, Swap-pop idiom avoid reallocation which results in more speed. I need the same here for range rather than 1 item

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking if `std::vector::erase()` is the best way to removes the last elements of a vector?

Comment: @YSC yes a kind of..

Comment: Yes, it's as optimized as can be

Comment: good question. With respect ot the `swap/pop-back` idea, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4442529/2412846) is one answer supporting it. I'm sure I've also saw timing result on SO, but I can't find them now.

Comment: The swap-pop idiom does not avoid reallocation. vector::erase is guaranteed to do no reallocation of memory at all. All the swap-pop idiom achieves is the minimisation of the number of elements copied, that is all

Comment: @davidhigh: Keep in mind that you're refering to an answer which predates C++11. Today, it can be even cheaper to move the element out (certainly for POD's that is a LOT cheaper).

Comment: @SJHowe sorry I meant that and wrote reallocation by mistake. Thanks for notifying

Answer (score 5):

> if I call `std::vector::erase` on a range which is represent the last n items of a `std::vector`, would it be optimised and behaves like multi `pop_back`?

If I understand you right, think the worry here is there shouldn't be any reseating operation like an erase in the middle.  If this is the case, the [standard guarantees](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) that (emphasis mine):

> #### Complexity
>
> Linear in the distance between first and last, **plus linear in the distance between last and end of the container**.

The emphasised part is for the reseating.  However, since this is zero, there will be no cost incurred when removing elements from the back.

A worthwhile thing to do is to disassemble the optimized output of some such code and see if this is just not a pointer assign/decrement operation in your toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

> As I know, if the order of the vector is not important, it is faster to use the swap-pop_back idiom for removing from std::vector.

Not sure what you mean by this. Anything involving multiple calls to pop-back is unlikely to be optimal.

> From the same perspective, if I call std::vector::erase on a range which is represent the last n items of a std::vector, would it be optimised

It depends on the library implementation, but almost certainly.

> and behaves like multi pop_back?

No

Comment: *As I know, if the order of the vector is not important, it is faster to use the swap-pop_back idiom for removing from std::vector.* means: if the order in the vector is not important, and you want to delete one element in the middle of the vector, instead of simply `erase`ing it from the middle, it is more efficient to swap this element with the last element in the vector and `pop_back`. Because the first alternative has to replace all elements after the erased one, whereas the second doesn't.